# Box2D в LibGDX и просто Box2D, в чем разница?

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx, box2d

Некоторое непонимание появилось при просмотре обучающих видео. Есть ли разница между просто установленным Box2D и Box2D, который можно выборочно установить при создание проекта в LibGDX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть, вы не сможете отдельно установить Box2D в libgdx проект потому, что Box2d - это C++ библиотека. Просто Libgdx оборачивает эту библиотеку так, чтобы ее можно было использовать из Java кода. То есть Box2d libgdx - это Box2d + Java обертка.